# Is it new arquillian container for run the infinispan-server 10?

Tags: testing, jboss-arquillian, infinispan

We use arquillian in our testsuite to run the infinispan-server. Before infinispan version 10, the infinispan-server was based on Wildfly and hence we were able to use the ManagedDeployableContainer as shown here: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/master/testsuite/integration-arquillian/tests/base/src/test/resources/arquillian.xml#L302 .

Since the infinispan 10, the infinispan-server is not based on Wildfly. Is it any other arquillian container, which can be used for such cases to start the infinispan-server in the "remote" mode?

The stacktrace, which we see is shown here: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-14494

Answer (score 1):

Marek, you should use our JUnit 4 / JUnit 5 testdriver which is documented here: https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/tree/master/server/testdriver